# $f$, $g$ are injective functions

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory

I have a question, let $E,F$ two sets.

$f:E\rightarrow F$

$g:F\rightarrow E$

and $f$, $g$ are injective functions.

$$\mathcal F=\{C\in\mathcal P(E),g(\complement_F^{f(C)})\subset\complement^C_E\}$$

How can I prove that the set above is nonempty?

Does the set above contain the empty set?

please help me with this question

Comment: You have a lot of unexplained notations there. What's P? What's that funny-looking C? Anyway, every set contains the empty set as a subset.

Comment: @GerryMyerson - the funny looking C is a old set-complement symbol, though this is fhe first time I've seen it used in this particular way (most commonly the C is a superscript, and the "universe" is not explicitly stated). @ ana nadi lwa3r - the common notation used today is "$g(F\setminus f(C)) \subset E\setminus C$".

Comment: Have you tried working out for yourself whether the empty set meets the condition? If $C = \emptyset$, then the condition becomes $g(F\setminus f(\emptyset)) \subset E\setminus \emptyset$. You should know what the definitions are just as well as the rest of us. What is $f(\emptyset)$? What is $E\setminus \emptyset$? Both are defined. Work out what they are, and see for yourself.